# return pointer access it in another function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a situation where I want to access the last element of an array of pointers. Just wondering how I would go about this.

Here's the code.

```
void Dealer::dealHoleCards()
{
    //Takes the last two cards off the deck and stores in an Array
    p_holeCards[0] = p_vecDeck.back();
    p_vecDeck.pop_back();
    p_holeCards[1] = p_vecDeck.back();
    p_vecDeck.pop_back();
}

Card* Dealer::getHoleCards()
{
    //Call deal and returns pointer to first element
    dealHoleCards();
    return p_holeCards[0];
}
```

So I need to pass this over to my Hand evaluator class for analysing against possible hands, but When I try to increment to the second element in the array it's sending it out of bounds? I have checked and the array is def getting populated with the correct values, so I'm a little confused. I think that I am just doing my incrementation wrong. I am a noob so not surprising that I'm confused lol.

So How would I increment it? Tried setting the value of getHoleCards() to a variable and then incremented the variable. That doesn't work so a little stumped.

Thanks in advance to the guys that know the answer to this probably simple question.

Sorry if vague tried to be as descriptive as possible.

Cheers in advance,
Paul

Comment: What is `p_holeCards`?  Is it an array of `Card` or of `Card *`?  In any case, you're not returning a pointer to its first element, you're returning the *value* of its first element.

Comment: Card*  sorry i should of said

Comment: I thought *pointer was the same as pointer[]

Comment: @PaulHashmi `*pointer` is the same as `pointer[0]`.

Comment: Thanks you were right as well, I wasn't accessing it correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with the return statement.

```
return p_holeCards[0];
```

Should be

```
return p_holeCards;
```

or

```
 return &p_holeCards[0];
```

Also don't forget Card** because its returning a pointer to a pointer where the actual object is.

Comment: thanks for that Brian my code should of been Card** as well.

Comment: Card** Dealer::getHoleCards()
    {
 dealHoleCards();
 return p_holeCards;
    }

Comment: Ahh yes, Sorry did it in a rush. Yeah you want to return a pointer that points to the actual object aka double pointer. Ill add that tidbit in